# How to Upload a Large File to MinIO

Tags: go, minio

I am using Minio for my project. Now I want to upload big files. For this purpose, I want to implement resumable uploading. For example, if my file size is 100MB, I want to save it 20 times with 5MB each, and after uploading the last part, combine them into one file. Please help me with this. How can I upload a big file in smaller parts and then combine them? I am using the Golang language.
Is my approach to saving large files correct? Am I using the right method for it?

I want to use ComposeObject method, but i dont know - it is right way or no

Comment: 1) `PutObject` does not support incremental/resumable upload as it's defined (in the AWS API) to be atomic (the operation either completely happens or completely fails); 2) re `ComposeObject`—does [this](https://github.com/minio/minio-java/issues/892#issuecomment-611480593) answer your question?

Comment: @kostix Thanks to this and several other posts, I found the answer. Thanks.